# Post title height changes depending on text length

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am new to gutenberg. The height of my post titles block changes depending on the length of the post title. I want the post titles blocks to be the same height. I have tried changing the CSS but was wondering is their a PHP solution to this or any other solution?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwXBX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below.
From below CSS will display the title based on your assigned width on css.

```css
.post-title-section{
      width: 90px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-title-section">
    <a href="https://yourdomain.com/post" class="post-title">This is test post title</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried but doesn't change the height of the block. The height changes based on the text length of the post title which is pulled in from the backend.

Comment: But after adding width on CSS the post title will automatically short and after that will automatically add '...' after the title.